# Peer-to-peer Java application

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

I want to create a peer to peer application that does not use `JXTA` framework. Just looking for some examples or good tutorials to get the basics down and then can go from there.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you make use of any tools or resources available to you before asking this question? (Note that I did not vote this question down).

Comment: i have done the basic client server application.. im unsure of where to go from there and after searching the web ive found nothing useful that can help me evolve my program... not sure why ppl would vote this down

Comment: @o f, As the question stands now, it is unanswerable. It's way too general and shows little to no research effort. Those are some of the many reasons why this question would be voted down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a socket based application.

Comment: think im just going to do this and store all clients in a file on a web where ports etc and assigned.